# Migration of Multisite WordPress site from http to https

Tags: multisite, migration

- I have completed the steps to update database to change the URL from http to https.

  - Then updated htacecss to add redirect rules.
  - But now anything except admin is going into endless loop of 301 redirect to itself.
  - Here is my .htaccess rules:

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-json/
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

In wp-config.php below is the configuration lines:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Please help to point the exact cause of endless loop of redirects.

Regards,
Vijay

Comment: did u clear your browser cache, 301 redirects are cached!

Comment: Yes, I did lots of times, also tested on vpn and private browsing modes. But it is redirecting only.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a missing rule in your htaccess file, try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

# ensure access to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-json/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#ensure you can access the network dashboard too.
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ wp/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

You can test your htaccess rules with this [tool](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).